# Figuring out that today is x number of days is after given date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have data in my database that returns the month/day/year data points for events.

What I want to do is check whether today is 20 days after the month/day/year that I get.

So far I have something like:

```
// Get date data
$day = $row['DAYOFMONTH(hike_date)'];
$year = $row['YEAR(hike_date)'];
$month = $row['MONTH(hike_date)'];

// Get today's date
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d");

// Create the date I am comparing with 
$date_string = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

My question is how do I compare it? And is the format going to matter in comparing the two dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Parse the month/day/year into a DateTime:

```
$other = date_create($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
```

Add 20 days to it:

```
$twenty_days_after = clone $other;
$twenty_days_after->modify('+20 days');
```

Compare it with today:

```
if ($today >= $twenty_days_after) {
    // today is 20 days after the month/day/year that you got
}
```

See [`date_create`](http://docs.php.net/date_create).

Comment: [When available](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) (>= 5.3.0) date_diff is the better route to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$database_date             = strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $year,$month,$day));
$twenty_days_from_now      = strtotime('+20 days');
$twenty_days_From_database = strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-%s +20 days', $year,$month,$day));
```

Using [`strttime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
strtotime()
```

function which will convert your dates into timestamp and you can compare them easier

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get date data
$day = $row['DAYOFMONTH(hike_date)'];
$year = $row['YEAR(hike_date)'];
$month = $row['MONTH(hike_date)'];

// Get today's date
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d");

// Create the date I am comparing with 
$date_string = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

if ( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( "+20 days", $date_string ) ) {
    //date is 20 days before today
}
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does magical things